# Python3: german letters and unicode utf8

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

When I start a python console I can do this:

```
>>> 'a' in string.ascii_lowercase + 'üä'
True
```

However if I start a python script that uses the same concept, I get:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte
```

This is my code that causes the error:

```
for x in record.vorname:
            if x not in string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + 'üöäÜÖÄ- ':
```

My python script starts with the following line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

What is the problem?

Comment: if you are on UNIX/Linux udr the file command to check the encoding of your file

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 (Notepad++)

Comment: Does that tell you what character encoding your file is

Comment: yes, according to settings it saves files in utf-8 by default

Comment: ` 'ü'.encode('cp1252')` -> `b'\xfc'` so it looks like your file is not being saved as UTF-8.